# iCloud notes deleted after I turned off Notes for Mail on my iPhone

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I am a writer and have (or had, rather) many valuable writings in my Notes app. However, the notes made duplicates of themselves. I read from a post online that in order to stop this, you were to turn off Notes in Mail. When I did this, I opened my Notes app only to see that all my notes had been deleted (I wrote them under iCloud instead of My Phone, since all my prior notes were there before the update where iCloud was introduced). I checked on icloud.com to see if my notes were there, but they were not. There was no "Recently Deleted" tab, either. According to Apple, this means they are not recoverable. Is there anything else I can try to do to recover my notes?

Still, I'm annoyed that the person who recommended turning off Notes in Mail did not warn in his/her post that such a thing would happen.

Comment: I'm sorry if this may sound harsh, but ...this is why we have backups. The modern adage is, "Any data stored in less than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary." The more important the data, the more important the multiplicity of backups.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning notes sync back on?
Go to Settings > iCloud and turn Notes back on. This may give you your notes back.